# Postgres - Replace special character # with some text

Tags: postgresql

i have a function which imports data from csv file - which in turn creates a table based on no of columns in csv file.

there is one line code which imports columns names from csv file and then renames temporary column name to actual names as per data in csv file.

```
format('select unnest(string_to_array(lower(replace(trim(insert_from_csv::text, ''()''),'' '',''_'')), '','')) from insert_from_csv where col_1 = %L', col_first)
and
format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
```

In the first statement i used 'replace' to remove spaces within the '_', but when i try to do the same for '#' gets error -b'ze in postgres # refers to comments.

Does anyone knows ways to replace '#' with 'some text'.

Function for reference:

```
create or replace function public.load_csv_file
(
target_table text,
csv_path text,
col_count integer
)

returns void as $$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or     spreadsheet

begin
set schema 'public';

create table insert_from_csv ();

-- add just enough number of columns
for iter in 1..col_count
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv add column col_%s text;', iter);
end loop;

-- copy the data from csv file
execute format('copy insert_from_csv from %L with delimiter '','' quote ''"'' csv ', csv_path);

iter := 1;
col_first := (select col_1 from insert_from_csv limit 1);

-- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(lower(replace(trim(insert_from_csv::text, ''()''),'' '',''_'')), '','')) from insert_from_csv where col_1 = %L', col_first)
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
    iter := iter + 1;
end loop;

-- delete the columns row
execute format('delete from insert_from_csv where %s = %L', col_first, col_first);

-- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
if length(target_table) > 0 then
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename to %I', target_table);
end if;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

CSV data:

```
date    Metrics # of Applications
01-Apr-17       95
02-Apr-17       122
03-Apr-17       110
04-Apr-17       94
05-Apr-17       122
06-Apr-17       93
07-Apr-17       97
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Geeme, could you please provide a sample of your csv file to reproduce your issue locally? thanks

Comment: you gave so much code, but none with `#` in it... please the code and error

Comment: @mabe2, i was looking for option to attach file but couldn't figure out. Csv file has below data:
    date Metrics # of Applications
    01-Apr-17  95
    02-Apr-17  122
    03-Apr-17  110
    04-Apr-17  94
    05-Apr-17  122
    06-Apr-17  93
    07-Apr-17  97